# Netbeans JSF - Creating executable JAR file

Tags: file, netbeans, jar, executable

I'm working at the moment on an JSF Project project. Everything is working fine. Creating .war-file, deploying it.

What I actually want is, to create a executable JAR-file for a single Class. In this Class I have a Main-method that sends an email after executing it.

I the past I have worked with Eclipse. And that was very easy.
Now I am working with Netbeans. I have red a lot of posts with the information to clean and build the project. Next to that checking the .dist folder for the JAR-files.

I have either the .dist folder, or any JAR-files in my Project folder for that correlate file.

How can I easily create that JAR-file in Netbeans?

Comment: No for my JSF Applikation I aleardy have a web-File (.war or .jar) and that works fine. What I want is a .jar-file only for one Class in that project. For example the Class GetDataAndSendMail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a native NetBeans project rather than Maven:

The build artefact of a project is defined by it's project type. A JSB/Web project is always build into a WAR file.

If there is one class in your project that you want to put into a JAR file, the clean solution would be to create a new "Java" project with that class (as your class clearly has no dependencies to your Web Application this should work).

For such a project NetBeans will automatically [create a runnable JAR](https://docs.oracle.com/netbeans/nb82/netbeans/NBDAG/build_japps.htm#NBDAG536) file if you configure the main method.

In your JSF project you can simply include that project as a library. If you enable "Build projects on classpath", the jar will automatically be build when you build the web application.

Another approach would be to customize the Ant script NetBeans uses internally and add a target that builds your executable JAR file from that single class.

Details on how to customize the IDE generated Ant script can be found in the manual:

https://docs.oracle.com/netbeans/nb82/netbeans/NBDAG/create_japps.htm#CHDDAHEB

Comment: Thanks a lot a_horse_with_no_name,

I will try to create a separate Java Project and include it to my webproject. I will give a feedback.

greetings

Comment: it works :) creating a new java-project with that separate class was the solution. After building the project in the .dist-folder was also the expected jar-file. Thanks a lot